# Call a php custom function that return a <div> inside another <div>

Tags: php, css

With these codes below i create 6 `<div>` that arrange in 2 columns and 3 rows,and then call custom **function writeMsg()** that return a `div` inside each of 6 `<div>`,but the  output has problem.

Thanks for your help.

**php codes**

```
  <?php
 function writeMsg() {
 $tab ="<div class='functiontest'>";
 echo "test";
 $tab .="</div>";
 return $tab;
 }
 $test = writeMsg();
  echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
   for( $i=0; $i < 6; $i++ ){
    echo "<div>" . $test . "</div>";
   }
  echo "</div>";
  ?>
```

**css**

```
  .functiontest{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#F4F5BD;
    float:left;
   }
   .wrapper{
    background-color:#F7ABAC;
    display:block;
    width:1000px;
    min-height:1000px;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
   .wrapper div{
    width:330px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display: block;
    background:#cccccc;
    text-align: center;
    }
   .wrapper div:nth-child(2n+1){
    clear:left;
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem? Can you put an **Expected result** vs **Actual result** at the bottom?

Comment: are you talking about the css problem or the php function you think have the problem? if you have problem with the text "test" then following answer helps. if its css problem please say yes or no

Comment: @ Isaac,the div that return from the function doesn't put inside the 6divs.

Comment: @Motsim,the problem i think is from css.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <?php
 function writeMsg() {
 $tab ="<div class='functiontest'>";
 $tab .= "test";
 $tab .="</div>";
 return $tab;
 }
 $test = writeMsg();
  echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
   for( $i=0; $i < 6; $i++ ){
    echo "<div>" . $test . "</div>";
   }
  echo "</div>";
  ?>
```

change css to

```
  <style>
    .wrapper div.functiontest{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#F4F5BD;
    float:left;
   }
   .wrapper{
    background-color:#F7ABAC;
    display:block;
    width:1000px;
    min-height:1000px;
    float:none;
    clear:both;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
   .wrapper div{
    width:330px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display: block;
    background:#cccccc;
    text-align: center;
    }
   .wrapper div:nth-child(2n+1){
    clear:left;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: My problem is the 'div' that return from function that doesnot appear in 6divs.

Comment: do u want to display function return in all 6 div or u just want to display the return in the Sixth div ???

Comment: i want that the div return from function appear in all 6 div.

Comment: php code is fine try change css with the one in my updated answer